# why always zero is coming as output?

Tags: python, string, list

Write a Python program to count the number of strings where the string length is 2 or more and the first and last character are same from a given list of strings

```
n=int(input())
count=0

for j in range(0,n):
    string=input()

for i in string:
    if len(i)>=2:
        if i[0]==i[-1]:
            count=count+1

print(count)
```

why output is always showing zero?

Comment: First off, you're not saving more than one string - first you loop through `n` strings, but (unless your indenting didn't come through), the second `for` loop only operates on the last `string`.

Answer (score 1):

You instead need to append the individual inputs to a `strings` array when building them, then loop over them and check your conditions:

```
n=int(input())
strings = []
count=0

for j in range(0,n):
    strings.append(input())

for i in strings:
    if len(i)>=2:
        if i[0]==i[-1]:
            count=count+1

print(count)
```